# Elemento inline

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá queria tira uma duvida porque um elemento `<a>` *inline* não funciona um `padding-top`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
a {
    padding-top: 80px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    text-transform: none;
    color: white;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Usa `display: inline-block;` e a âncora já vai respeitar esse `padding-top`.

```css
a {
 display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 80px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    color: white;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="">Foo</a>
    <a href="">Bar</a>
</div>
```

A razão porque não funciona é porque o elemento tem `display: inline;` e elementos `inline` não respeitam `padding` com é esperado. Por defenição o `a` é um [elemento inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements). Há um artigo antigo sobre isso [aqui](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)<sup>Em Inglês</sup>. Nesse artigo diz *"While padding can be applied to all sides of an inline element, only left and right padding will have an effect on surrounding content."*, ou seja só o padding lateral é respeitado.

Exemplos:

Sem alterar o `display`: https://jsfiddle.net/mnj85kp2/
Com `display: inline-block;`: https://jsfiddle.net/mnj85kp2/1/

Comment: Olá amigo gostaria de saber porque ele não respeita

Comment: @Henrique a minha resposta funciona como queres? Juntei mais info na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado amigo me ajudo muito.